# Can Nautilus automatically close the window after a file is opened?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

In Mac's OS X, if you hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while opening a file, the Finder window will automatically close (after opening the file). This works whether you double-click the file or use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>). Is there an equivalent in Nautilus?

Comment: Sounds like an extension worth programming. Maybe there is a place this could be suggested?

Comment: @MadMike I'm using KDE now, so I wouldn't chase it up myself. I agree that it'd still be a useful function though.

Comment: I no longer use Nautilus, so I'm going to [close](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3773/53508) this as "too localised". Mods, please let me know if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, its actually very simple.

Install CCSM if you don't already have it.

In the 'commands' section of ccsm assign the command 'close nautilus' to the keybinding you want and there you have it.  VERY SIMPLE AND POSSIBLE!

In this case your keybinding would be the 'option' key and left click mouse button, just like Mac OSX

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

From the command-line, somewhat similar behavior is possible.

I tried with `nautilus` but it doesn't support the '`quit`' option with 'URI's (folder paths etc) but `thunar` does support that.  So the below would open the file specified in its associated editor without starting `thunar`.

```
thunar -q myfolder/myfile.properties
```

Let us know if this helps.